# Screen Hunter and Dual Screens

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, screenshot

I have a laptop + second screen setup up work with the second screen situated above the laptop screen.

I also have Screen Hunter installed from which I take screenshots with for bug reports / examples, etc etc.

The problem is that screen hunter will only include the laptop (primary) screen and ignores the top one.

Is there a work around or fix anyone knows for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to [Screen Hunter](http://wisdom-soft.com/products/screenhunter.htm) Pro?

> Even more capture options,
>   **multi-monitor**, adjustable area, user
>   defined area, multi-object and text

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately getting that approve has as much chance of happening in the next 5 years as <insert nearly impossible event here> :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? 
http://www.fiastarta.com/PrtScr/

Looks like it's free.

Or this one... http://picpick.wiziple.net/features

Answer (score 0):

[Faststone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) (version 6.5 is shareware) claims multiple monitor support.

[Version 5.3](http://download.cnet.com/FastStone-Capture/3000-2192_4-10645361.html) is free, but I can't find a claim to multiple monitor support.